# Invalid heap error when trying to copy elements from a Map to a compatible priority Queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

My program makes a frequency map of characters (which I store in , surprise surprise, a Map), I am trying to copy each element from this map into a Priority Queue so that I can have a sorted copy of these values (I plan to make further use of the Q, that's why am not sorting the map) , but whenever I try to copy these values , the program executes fine for the first two or three iterations and fails on the fourth citing an "Invalid heap" error.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, so I am posting the code for the classes in question.

```
#include "srcFile.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

srcFile::srcFile(std::string s_flName)
{
    // Storing the file name
    s_fileName= s_flName;
}

srcFile::srcFile()
{
    // Default constructor (never to be used)
}

srcFile::~srcFile(void)
{
}

void srcFile::dispOverallMap ()
{
    std::map<char,int>::iterator dispIterator;
dispIterator = map_charFreqDistribution.begin();
charElement *currentChar;

std::cout<<"\n Frequency distribution map \n";
while(dispIterator != map_charFreqDistribution.end())
{
    std::cout<< "Character : " << (int)dispIterator->first << " Frequency : "<< dispIterator->second<<'\n';
    currentChar = new charElement(dispIterator->first,dispIterator->second);

    Q_freqDistribution.push(*currentChar);
    dispIterator++;

    // delete currentChar;
}

while(!Q_freqDistribution.empty())
{
    std::cout<<'\n'<<"Queue Element : " << (int)Q_freqDistribution.top().ch_elementChar << " Frequency : " << Q_freqDistribution.top().i_frequency;
    Q_freqDistribution.pop();
}
}
```

map_charFreqDistribution has already been populated, if I remove the line 
Q_freqDistribution.push(*currentChar);
Then I can verify that the Map is indeed there.

Also , both the Q and the use charElement as the template type , its nothing except the character and its frequency, along with 2 pointers to facilitate tree generation (unused upto this point)

Adding the definition of charElement on request

```
#pragma once
class charElement
{
public:
    // Holds the character for the element in question
char ch_elementChar;

// Holds the number of times the character appeared in the file
int i_frequency;

// Left pointer for tree
charElement* ptr_left;
// Right pointer for tree
charElement* ptr_right;

charElement(char,int);
charElement(void);
~charElement(void);
void operator=(charElement&);
};

class compareCharElt
{
public:
bool operator()(charElement &operand1,charElement &operand2)
{
    // If the frequency of op1 < op2 then return true
    if(operand1.i_frequency < operand2.i_frequency) return true;

    // If the frequency of op1 > op2 then return false
    if(operand1.i_frequency > operand2.i_frequency)return false;

    // If the frequency of op1 == op2 then return true (that is priority is indicated to be less even though frequencies are equal)
    if(operand1.i_frequency == operand2.i_frequency)return false;
}
};
```

Definition of Map and Queue

```
// The map which holds the frequency distribution of all characters in the file
    std::map<char,int> map_charFreqDistribution;
    void dispOverallMap();

// Create Q which holds character elements
std::priority_queue<charElement,std::vector<charElement>,compareCharElt>                 Q_freqDistribution;
```

P.S.This may be a noob question, but Is there an easier way to post blocks of code , putting 4 spaces in front of huge code chunks doesn't seem all that efficient to me! Are pastebin links acceptable here ?

Comment: How are types `charElement` and `Q_freqDistribution` defined? Creating a new `currentChar`, then passing in the object itself and not its pointer, and finally deleting the `currentChar` looks like a suspicious sequence.

Comment: If you never intend to use your default constructor, you don't have to define one. Just use the explicit constructor.

Comment: @eran I added the definitions to the main question. 
The new -> add  -> delete thing seems to be JAVA hangover (the language I use at work) but essentially I need a new object to be created each iteration and added to the Queue. (Had a brainwave while typing this , should I not delete the variable as it is being held as a reference in the Queue)

Comment: @JaredFriese Thanks for the tip, this is a rough code draft, that method was added as a stub when the code was in an earlier draft, the comment was to remind me to remove it once I am done.

Comment: made the change where I no longer delete the object after pushing (I wasn't doing this in earlier drafts of the code either) , it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you doing anything with `ptr_left` and `ptr_right` without initializing them? What is the exact line of the error?

Comment: no , I haven't touched those two yet, the part which uses those two comes much later in the code.
 The error occurs here :     Q_freqDistribution.push(*currentChar);

Comment: Have you noticed that there's a button to indent a whole block of text by four spaces?

Comment: Why did you post so much code in the first place? Are you sure that `srcFile::~srcFile()` is really necessary? And what's with [passing strings per copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/) and not using [initialization lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/)? You might need [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: @sbi I had not posted so much code , Just the first class . The rest I added on request.
 The destructor is an ide generated stub , I am just more concerned with getting stuff working at this point , will trim it down when required. I will look into the "passing strings per copy" issue thanks.

Comment: @angryInsomniac: I had asked this before I had even seen you had added the second class. Usually, when asking a question, you want a small (<20 lines), self-containing, compiling (unless that's the problem, of course), repro case, no classes unless necessary and no other unnecessary code either. Creating and copying maps and deques is certainly easily done in a single function (preferably in `main()`), nothing else is needed. Also, in 75% of all cases, by boiling down the code to such a small repro you will find the error yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector is reallocating and invalidating your pointers. You need to use a different data structure, or an index into the vector, instead of a raw pointer. When you insert elements into a vector, then pointers to the contents become invalid.

```
while(dispIterator != map_charFreqDistribution.end())
{
    std::cout<< "Character : " << (int)dispIterator->first << " Frequency : "<< dispIterator->second<<'\n';
    currentChar = new charElement(dispIterator->first,dispIterator->second);

    Q_freqDistribution.push(*currentChar);
    dispIterator++;

    delete currentChar;
}
```

Completely throws people off because it's very traditional for people to have huge problems when using `new` and `delete` directly, but there's actually no need for it *whatsoever* in this code, and everything is actually done by value.

You have two choices. Pick a structure (e.g. `std::list`) that does not invalidate pointers, or, allocate all charElements on the heap directly and use something like `shared_ptr` that cleans up for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentChar = new charElement(dispIterator->first,dispIterator->second);

Q_freqDistribution.push(*currentChar);
dispIterator++;

delete currentChar;
```

In the above code, you create a new `charElement` object, then push it, and then delete it. When you call delete, that object no longer exists -- not even in the queue. That's probably not what you want.